# Rails - using multiple email providers in single app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Anyway I can use multiple email providers within the same Rails 3 app ?

Context
1. Im using postmark for sending out mails currently (using delayed job)
2. Our app also needs to send out some mass emails - for which we will be using a separate provider.

Now I dont want to separate out and create a new app for the mass emailing part. How can I use/choose different email providers at the point of sending email ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: @Msencenb That describes ActionMailer but it doesn't go beyond configuring global SMTP settings.  Was there a specific portion of the guide I missed?

Answer (score 7):

You can override ActionMailer settings on a per mailer basis, for example

```
class BulkMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  self.smtp_settings = {...}
end
```

will cause `BulkMailer` and its subclasses to use those settings.

The one thing to be wary of is not to change `smtp_settings` in place, i.e. do *not* do something like `self.smtp_settings[:user_name] = 'blah'` as this would be acting on the shared settings rather than creating new settings private to `BulkMailer`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using mailserver fallback in my application, so when one mail server is down it switches mailserver. Your problem is similar, except you don't need to alias the old `Mail::Message.deliver` and use `Mail::Message.mass_deliver` for instance.

This is how you do it:

```
Mail::Message.class_eval do
  def mass_deliver
     self.delivery_method.settings = {
                                      :address => "smtp.massdeliverserver.com",
                                      :port => 587,
                                      :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
                                      :user_name => 'mass-email@quadnode.com',
                                      :password => 'yourpassword',
                                      :authentication => 'plain',
                                      :enable_starttls_auto => true
                                     }
     deliver
  end
end
```

Then you could use `YourMailer.your_method.deliver` to use defalt settings you provided in `environment.rb` for `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` and `YourMailer.your_method.mass_deliver` to use the other server settings.

Put the code inside some file in `config/initializers` and `mass_deliver` method will be available for any `Mail::Message` instance in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mass email list to which you need to send out from say `mass-email@email.com` and some other emails for other purpose from `otheremail@email.com`

You need to do these steps if i am getting the question correct ::

1. Remove the `default` from `default :from`  if you have written it.
2. Create an action mailer for `mass-email` and put up the `:from => "mass-email@email.com"`

   1. Go to your `environment.rb` file and fill up the details like this

   `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {`

   `:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",`

   `:port                 => 587,`

   `:domain               => 'yourdomain.com',`

   `:user_name            => 'mass-email@quadnode.com',`

   `:password             => 'yourpassword',`

   `:authentication       => 'plain',`

   `:enable_starttls_auto => true
   }`

You can create it for as many files as you wish.

Hope it helps.